# Keep input validation CSS class when using select2

Tags: html, css, validation, jquery-select2

On my form I have a dropdownlist where I am using [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage).

Here is my razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, ViewBag.StateName as SelectList, "-- Select State --", new { id = "CreateState", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery Validation for client side validation.

If I leave the dropdownlist without a selected value then I would expect a validation error, which I am recieving but not the corresponding css class that outlines the box in red.. specifically `input-validation-error`.

Here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the `City` gets the red outline, whereas the State which is using Select2 does not, even though both get the validation message.

When I check the rendered HTML from the Razor code I see this for the dropdownlist:

```
<select name="StateId" tabindex="-1" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible input-validation-error" id="CreateState" aria-hidden="true" data-val-required="The State field is required." data-val-number="The field State must be a number." data-val="true">
<option value="">-- Select State --</option>
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Alaska</option>
<option value="3">Arizona</option>
<option value="4">Arkansas</option>
<option value="5">California</option>
<option value="6">Colorado</option>
<option value="7">Connecticut</option>
<option value="8">Delaware</option>
<option value="9">Florida</option>
<option value="10">Georgia</option>
<option value="11">Hawaii</option>
<option value="12">Idaho</option>
<option value="13">Illinois</option>
<option value="14">Indiana</option>
<option value="15">Iowa</option>
<option value="16">Kansas</option>
<option value="17">Kentucky</option>
<option value="18">Louisiana</option>
<option value="19">Maine</option>
<option value="20">Maryland</option>
<option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="22">Michigan</option>
<option value="23">Minnesota</option>
<option value="24">Mississippi</option>
<option value="25">Missouri</option>
<option value="26">Montana</option>
<option value="27">Nebraska</option>
<option value="28">Nevada</option>
<option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="30">New Jersey</option>
<option value="31">New Mexico</option>
<option value="32">New York</option>
<option value="33">North Carolina</option>
<option value="34">North Dakota</option>
<option value="35">Ohio</option>
<option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="37">Oregon</option>
<option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="39">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="40">South Carolina</option>
<option value="41">South Dakota</option>
<option value="42">Tennessee</option>
<option value="43">Texas</option>
<option value="44">Utah</option>
<option value="45">Vermont</option>
<option value="46">Virginia</option>
<option value="47">Washington</option>
<option value="48">West Virginia</option>
<option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="50">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Now that gets the `input-validation-error` class but obviously not showing the red outline.

The `select2` generates this:

```
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap" style="width: 280px;" dir="ltr">
    <span class="selection">
        <span tabindex="0" class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-CreateState-container">
            <span title="-- Select State --" class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-CreateState-container">-- Select State --</span>
            <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

Using zgood's answer here is the result:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Changing zgood's answer I was able to use this:

```
.input-validation-error ~ .select2[![enter image description here][3]][3] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Which resulted in this:

[image]

But now the red outline doesn't match the form of the textbox.

Comment: Can you check and see if your `.form-group` div gets the class `.has-error`? I solved this before by adding the style `.has-error .select2-selection__rendered { border: 1px soild red; }`, but I am unsure if the jquery validation lib added this class or if I had some other js that added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this style might help you:

```
.input-validation-error ~ .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will select the rendered area of the select2 dropdown when its previous sibling (the original `select`) gets the class `input-validation-error` during validation.

They key is the [preceding element selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) `~`

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj0hkzpq/)

**Update**

It actually might be better to target the `.select2-selection` instead of `.select2-selection__rendered`. Try updating the style to this:

```
.input-validation-error ~ .select2 .select2-selection {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Quick question, when I do pick a selection in the dropdown, is there anyway for that validation message and css to go away like the other textboxes?  If another textbox is empty and has the validation message but then I type something in it.. the validation message disappears

Comment: @T_Roy You will have to add a `change` event to remove the `.input-validation-error` class manually. It would probably look something like this: `$("select[name=StateId").on("change", function(e) { $(this).parent(".form-group").find(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error"); })`. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but is not working.  I have this:    `$("select[name=StateId]").on("change",
        function(e) {
            $(this).parent(".form-group").find(".input-validation-error").removeClass(".input-validation-error");
        });`

Comment: @T_Roy Try removing the `.` from `removeClass(".inpu‌​t-validation-error")‌​;`. So it will become `removeClass("inpu‌​t-validation-error")‌​;`

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this would work because originally we are giving the red outline to `.select2 .select2-selection` element that are preceded by an element with the class name `.input-validation-error`.. so we need to revert the color change back to normal along with removing the validation message.